# PDO prepare method gets undefined from class to class

Tags: php, class, pdo, prepared-statement

Here is my code

```
class db{
public function connect(){
      try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname = $dbname", $user , $pass);        
        return this->$db;
      }
     catch (PDOException $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();        
     } 
  }
```

So then I have another class to get some data from the database

```
class getData{

public function getData($table,$where) {
//$where is dynamic and is like array('user'=>$username,'pass'=>$password))

   $db = new db();

    foreach ($where as $value){
        $where_string.=(" AND ".$value."=:".$value);                
    } 
    $where_string=substr($where_string,5);
  // end up with foo=:foo AND foo=:foo to add in the query

    $query_array = array();
    foreach ($where as $value){     
        $query_array[$value]= $value;
    }
  //end up with array(foo=>foo, foo=>foo); to add in the query


    $statement = $db->prepare("select id from table = :table where " .$where_string);
    $statement->execute($query_array);
    $row = $statement->fetch(); 

  }

}
```

The `$where` var in `getData` is not fixed so I have to loop it and construct the where part of the query and the binding part of prepared statements.

I always end up with `Fatal error: Call to undefined method db::prepare() in /home/projectAwesome/public_html/mystuff.php on line 241`

How do I fix this? PHP should see the prepare method because it is a global module of php and is running. 
Thanks

***UPDATE***

Now my code is

```
class db extends PDO{
  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pass;
  private $name;
  private $link;
  private $error;
  private $errno;
  private $query;
  function __construct($myhost='localhost', $myuser='aaa', $mypass='bbb', $myname='ccc', $myconn = 1) {
    $this -> host = $myhost;
    $this -> user = $myuser;
    $this -> pass = $mypass;
    if (!empty($myname)) $this -> name = $myname;      
    if ($myconn == 1) $this -> connect();
  }
  function __destruct() {
    @mysql_close($this->link);
  }
  public function connect(){
      try{
        $host = $this -> host;
        $dbname = $this -> name;
        $user = $this -> user;
        $pass = $this -> pass;   
        $charset = 'utf8';

      $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
      $opt = [
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
       PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
       PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
      ];  
      $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
        return $db;
      }
     catch (PDOException $e){
             echo $e->getMessage();
     } 
  }
}
```

and then the other class

```
class getData{
public function getData($table,$where) {
$db = new db();

    $where_string   = "";
    foreach ($where as $key=>$value){
        $where_string.=($value."=:".$value." AND ");                
     }
    $where_string=rtrim($where_string, " AND ");



    $query_array = array();
    foreach ($where as $value){
           $query_array[$value]= $value;
    }


    $statement = $db->prepare("select id from" .$table. "where ".$where_string);
    $statement->execute($query_array);
    $row = $statement->fetch(); 


  }
}
```

and the error is now

`Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called in /home/... on line 254`

`Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null in /home/... on line 255`

Please advice. Thank you

Comment: `mysql:host=$host; dbname = $dbname` there should NOT be any spaces in there. So change it to `mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname` and try it again. If that makes it work, then there is a duplicate for this somewhere.

Comment: Your `connect` function assigns a connection to `$db` (i.e. local scope) and never assigns it to an object property even though you try and `return $this->db`.

Comment: And `this->$db` isn't right.

Comment: quite a few more errors other than what I mentioned in my comment to them then @JonStirling

Comment: `select id from table = :table` that's another syntax error there. You need to check for the *real* errors where you are not doing that. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: AND your where code doesn't even make sense. You can only ever set column values to the column names.

Comment: I have obviously have fallen onto deaf ears. *sigh* Edit: Oh, so now they listen. *Facepalm*. But still didn't pick up on `select id from table = :table`.

Comment: I withdrew my answer as there is an error on nearly every line of this code, and I dont have the time to rewrite your script for you. VTC as nonsence. **Hit the books**

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated my question. Thanks for pointing out the `table` syntax error. It would be nice if you gave it another look. Thanks again.

Comment: `@mysql_close($this->link);` Oh here we go round the mulberry bush like a ??????? **HIT THE BOOKS**

Answer (score 2):

There are a few observed oversights on your part. 1.) The connect() Method in the db Class has no way to access the variable: $host, $user, $pass, etc. 2.) The getData Method in your getData Class instantiates the db Class without any way of the db Class getting information about the $host, $user, $pass, etc variable. It might be ideal to define those variables as constants instead and then you don't have to pass them all the time. Otherwise, this could do the trick for you:

```
    <?php

        class db extends PDO{
            public function connect($host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
                try {
                    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

                    return $this->$db;
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }

        class getData{

            public function getData($table, $where, $host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
                //$where is dynamic and is like array('user'=>$username,'pass'=>$password))                 
                $db             = new db($host, $dbname, $user, $pass);
                $where_string   = "";

                foreach ($where as $key=>$value){
                    $where_string .= ($value."=:".$value . " AND ");
                }
                // REMOVE SURPLUS " AND " TO THE RIGHT OF THE STRING... 
                $where_string = rtrim($where_string, " AND ");
                // $where_string = substr($where_string,5);  //<== WHY substr? WHAT'S YOUR INTENTION HERE? 
                // end up with foo=:foo AND foo=:foo to add in the query

                $query_array    = array();
                foreach ($where as $value){
                    $query_array[$value]= $value;
                }
                //end up with array(foo=>foo, foo=>foo); to add in the query


                $statement  = $db->prepare("select id from table " . $table . " where " . $where_string);
                $statement->execute($query_array);
                $row        = $statement->fetch();

            }

        }
```

**UPDATE: DB CLASS**

```
    <?php
        class db extends PDO{
            private $host;
            private $user;
            private $pass;
            private $dbh;
            private $name;
            private $link;
            private $error;
            private $errno;
            private $query;
            function __construct($myhost='localhost', $myuser='aaa', $mypass='bbb', $myname='ccc', $myconn = 1) {
                $this -> host = $myhost;
                $this -> user = $myuser;
                $this -> pass = $mypass;

                if (!empty($myname)){
                    $this->name = $myname;
                }
                if ($myconn == 1){
                    if(isset($this->dbh)){
                        return $this->dbh;
                    }
                    return $this->connect();
                }
            }
            function __destruct() {
                $this->dbh  = null;
            }
            public function connect(){
                try{
                    $host       = $this -> host;
                    $dbname     = $this -> name;
                    $user       = $this -> user;
                    $pass       = $this -> pass;
                    $charset    = 'utf8';

                    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
                    $opt = [
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                    ];
                    $this->dbh  = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
                    return $this->dbh ;
                }
                catch (PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `mysql:host=$host; dbname = $dbname` - [*Read my comment about that to the OP...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726918/pdo-prepare-method-gets-undefined-from-class-to-class#comment62925147_37726918) along with the other ones. Your answer will fail. Look at this `select id from table = :table where` what's not right here? You didn't see the comments obviously.

Comment: `select id from table = :table` that's a big syntax error there.

Comment: @Fred-ii-      Clearer than crystal... ;-)

Comment: @Poiz I Updated my question thanks to your code. It would be nice if you want to give it another look. Thanks